# How do I use filters correctly?

Tags: libgdx

Why doesn't the Player collide with the Ground? Did I use the filter wrong?
I store all my constants in a Class called Constants. Here is the code I use :

```
for (MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(2).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
    Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();

    bDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bDef.position.set((rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2)
    / Constants.PPM, (rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2)
    / Constants.PPM);

    body = world.createBody(bDef);

    shape.setAsBox(rect.getWidth() / 2 / Constants.PPM,
    rect.getHeight() / 2 / Constants.PPM);
    fDef.shape = shape;
    body.createFixture(fDef);

    fDef.filter.categoryBits = Constants.BRICK_BIT;
    fDef.filter.maskBits = Constants.PLAYER1_BIT;
}
```

Here is how I define my Player. I am if thats a dump question, but I am a complete newbie in LibGDX...

```
public void defineMainPlayer1() {
    BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
    bDef.position.set(128 / Constants.PPM, 256 / Constants.PPM);
    bDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2body = world.createBody(bDef);

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(42 / 2 / Constants.PPM, 94 / 2 / Constants.PPM);

    FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
    fDef.shape = shape;
    fDef.filter.categoryBits = Constants.PLAYER1_BIT; // Setting the filter
    // for my Player
    fDef.filter.maskBits = Constants.BRICK_BIT;

    b2body.createFixture(fDef).setUserData(this);

    EdgeShape head = new EdgeShape();
    head.set(new Vector2(-30 / Constants.PPM, 49 / Constants.PPM),

    new Vector2(30 / Constants.PPM, 49 / Constants.PPM));
    fDef.shape = head;
    fDef.isSensor = true;

    b2body.createFixture(fDef).setUserData("head");

}
```

Comment: Can you show your the definitions of Constants.BRICK_BIT and Constants.BRICK_BIT?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order of

```
body.createFixture(fDef);

fDef.filter.categoryBits = Constants.BRICK_BIT;
fDef.filter.maskBits = Constants.PLAYER1_BIT;
```

to

```
fDef.filter.categoryBits = Constants.BRICK_BIT;
fDef.filter.maskBits = Constants.PLAYER1_BIT;

body.createFixture(fDef);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an example below, these should give you a clear explanation and ideas.

```
short CAT_PLAYER = 0x001;
short CAT_ENEMY = 0x002;
short CAT_SENSOR = 0x004;
short CAT_WALL = 0x008;

short MASK_PLAYER = ~CAT_PLAYER; // cannot collide to a player
short MASK_ENEMY = ~CAT_ENEMY; // cannot collide to a enemy
short MASK_SENSOR = CAT_PLAYER; // can only collide to a player
short MASK_WALL = -1; // can collide to all
```

And a simple filter for the fixture of a player. This means the player can collide to all except itself.

```
filter.categoryBits = CAT_PLAYER;
filter.maskBits = MASK_PLAYER;
```